# Redsys Conexión InSite error SIS0218: El comercio no permite operaciones seguras por las entradas "operaciones" o "WebService"

Tags: javascript, html, pago-in-app

Estoy implementando el pago In-Site de Redsys y para ello estoy siguientdo las instrucciones de su página https://pagosonline.redsys.es/conexion-insite.html

Tras diversos problemas como por ejemplo el código de error **msg18** que he solucionado cambiando mi entorno de desarrollo a http://localhost:8012 (que es uno de los pocos permitidos), he podido enviar la petición y recibir el ID de operación (token) de vuelta.

A partir de allí, siempre siguiendo el manual, hay que lanzar la operación de autorización mediante una petición REST que he implementado según indicado.

Pero no hay manera de que funcione correctamente ya que siempre me viene de vuelta el error

> SIS0218: El comercio no permite operaciones seguras por las entradas "operaciones" o "WebService"

Y es dónde ahora mismo estoy estancado.

Si alguna alma noble y bondadosa puede darme una pista, se lo agradecería.

Saludos.

P.D.: Los dominios que están permitidos en el entorno de pruebas, según he visto en el .js que se descarga al generarse el iframe, son los siguientes:

```
http://127.0.0.1
http://localhost:1337
http://127.0.0.1:8085
http://localhost:8012
http://localhost:8000
http://127.0.0.1:8000
https://pae-ya.eu *
file://*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al parecer la documentación de Redsys está desactualizada. Tendrías que añadir un nuevo parametro a la consulta

```
$redsys->setMerchantDirectPayment(true);
```

En el caso de que trabajes con json tendrias que añadirlo al cuerpo del ***Ds_MerchantParameters***

```
{
  "DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT": "145",
  "DS_MERCHANT_CURRENCY": "978",
  "DS_MERCHANT_CVV2": "123",
  "DS_MERCHANT_EXPIRYDATE": "1512",
  "DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE": "999008881",
  "DS_MERCHANT_ORDER": "1446068581",
  "DS_MERCHANT_PAN": "454881********04",
  "DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL": "1",
  "DS_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONTYPE": "0",
  "DS_MERCHANT_DIRECTPAYMENT": "true" // Este es el parametro a añadir
}
```

Esta información para resolver la issue la encontré en este comentario: https://github.com/ssheduardo/sermepa/issues/80#issuecomment-1060461856